# How to import and export different functions of the same name in C++

Tags: c++, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I'm writing the runtime library for a custom language and I have some issues getting it to work under Linux.
I need to create a shared object file which exports the symbols specified by the runtime specification.
Some of these names conflict with the standard libraries and some are invalid C++ identifiers.

On Windows, I can simply pass a module definition file to the MSVC linker, but `ld` doesn't seem to provide an equivalent solution. I've read up a bit about linker scripts and found they offer similar functionality, but they only solved the problem partially. They allow me to change the exported name where it's not a valid C++ identifier, but cause new issues with standard library name conflicts.

The line `exit = _ZN7runtime4exitEi;` for example also causes the **imported** symbol to be replaced, which causes an endless recursion when `exit` is called, which ultimately results in a segfault (which is one way to exit I guess).

Library source (runtime.cpp):

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

namespace runtime {
    [[ noreturn ]] void __cdecl exit(int code) {
        ::exit(code);
    }

    // can't call this "not", because that's a keyword
    int __cdecl bitwise_not(int a) {
        return ~a;
    }
    
    // exported as "object::.ctor"
    void __cdecl object_ctor(runtime::object* instance) {
        // empty
    }
}
```

MSVC module definition (exports64.def):

```
LIBRARY runtime
EXPORTS
    exit=?exit@runtime@@YAXH@Z
    not=?bitwise_not@runtime@@YAHH@Z
    object::.ctor=?object_ctor@runtime@@YAXPEAUobject@1@@Z
```

Linker script (libruntime64.map):

```
exit = _ZN7runtime4exitEi;
not = _ZN7runtime11bitwise_notEi
object::.ctor = _ZN7runtime11object_ctorEPNS_6objectE;

/* use the default linker script */
SECTIONS { } INSERT AFTER .text;
```

Another approach I tried was to use the `--wrap` option of `ld`, but that doesn't change the exported name. Passing `--wrap=exit` with the following code correctly resolves `__real_exit` to the imported `exit` function, but the exported name remains `__wrap_exit`.

```cpp
namespace runtime {
    extern "C" [[ noreturn ]] void __real_exit(int code);
    extern "C" [[ noreturn ]] void __wrap_exit(int code) {
        __real_exit(code);
    }
}
```

So I guess the core of my question is this: How do I link a shared object file that imports and exports two different symbols with the same name?

In case this is relevant, the frontend I use is Clang and the complete command line looks like this:

```sh
clang -Wl,--script=runtime/libruntime64.map \
    -lstdc++ -lm -std=c++17 \
    -fpic -shared -Wl,-verbose \
    -o out/libruntime.so runtime/*.cpp
```